# Where did my reputation go?

Tags: support, reputation, deletion

I just noticed, that I lost $15$ reputation points. It is common that you lose some reputations points from time to time due to the deletion of members. Normally the loss is shown on your profile. But not in this case.
So I wonder what is the reason for the loss?

Comment: A question was deleted on which you had an accepted answer.

Comment: See also: [I had reputation of 104 it fell down to 96 the next time I logged in. Why is that?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21311) and [Where reputation disappears](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18884).

Comment: If you don't lose too much, don't worry. Just write two new answers.

Comment: I did not worry about the loss of reputations. I worried, because I did not know where it came from, because normally you see it.

Comment: There is a loss of 20 reputation logged today (well after you noticed the drop) in your timeline.  Perhaps the software is prone to such a delay?  I'd never noticed what the gap in timing could be.

Comment: A user got removed.